# Why do I receive this error message: Elaboration time unknown or bad value encountered for generate if-statement condition expression?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When I was writing my Verilog code, I keep receiving the below error:

```
Error-[V2KGEUV] Unknown or bad value for genvar
design.sv, 7
" if (k[7:0] != k[31:24]) begin : genblk1   assign error = 1; end"
  Instance/Generate block name: hamming_TB.dut
  Elaboration time unknown or bad value encountered for generate if-statement 
  condition expression.
  Please make sure it is elaboration time constant.
```

my design and test bench are

design

```
module hamming_code_checker(
    input [31:0] k,
    output g
);
reg error = 0;

if (k[7:0] != k[31:24]) 
begin
assign error = 1;
end

assign g = error;
endmodule

// test bench

// Testbench for Hamming Code Checker
module hamming_TB();
// Test input signals
reg [31:0] hamming_code;
// Test output signals
wire error;

// Instantiate the design under test (DUT)
hamming_code_checker dut(hamming_code, error);

// Define test cases
// Correct Hamming code
reg [31:0] correct_code = 32'h0A1B2C3;
// Incorrect Hamming code
reg [31:0] incorrect_code = 32'h0A1B2C4;

// Test initial block
initial begin
// Test correct Hamming code
hamming_code = correct_code;
#1;
assert(error == 0) else $error("Test failed for correct Hamming code");
// Test incorrect Hamming code
hamming_code = incorrect_code;
#1;
assert(error == 1) else $error("Test failed for incorrect Hamming code");
$finish;
end

endmodule
```

initially, I don't add **assign** before **error = 1;** and I got this

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "design.sv", 9: token is '='
  error = 1;
         ^
```

Somebody on the internet told me to add **assign**, but I keep getting error message above.

Answer (score 1):

The following represents a 'generate' block in verilog.

```
if (k[7:0] != k[31:24]) 
begin
assign error = 1;
end
```

Note that keywords `generate..endgenerate` are optional and just are not used there.
Generate blocks expect genvars and parameters. `k` is neither a genvar nor a parameter. So, it is illegal.

Using just `error = 1;` is a syntactic error in Verilog. You should surround it with an always block or use an assign statement, however, whoever suggested you to use assign in this case was wrong. It cannot be used on registers (reg). Only an always block can.

My guess is that you need to write something like the following:

```
module hamming_code_checker(
    input [31:0] k,
    output g
);
reg error = 0;

always @* begin // use an always block here.
   if (k[7:0] != k[31:24]) 
   begin
      error = 1;
   end
end

assign g = error;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

From a Verilog compiler point of view, when it sees an `if/else`, it expects:

**A)** it to be inside a procedural block, such as an `always` block.

or

**B)** the `if` condition must evaluate to a constant (not using variable signals like `k`)

You get the errors because the compiler guessed you were trying to implement a `generate` block.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27. *Generate constructs*.

> Somebody on the internet told me to add assign

Yes, you can use an `assign`.  In fact, you can greatly simplify your code like this:

```
module hamming_code_checker(
    input [31:0] k,
    output g
);
    // Set g only if LSByte is different from MSByte
    assign g = (k[7:0] != k[31:24]);
endmodule
```

Comment: Wow! It is simpler than Serge's way. By doing so, "error" is not needed. Thank you for replying.